# Load Spell check dictionary

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spell-checking

I'm planning to build a spell check service and I'm pretty sure that the dictionary is going to be huge as I'm going to load it with millions of data.

I cannot afford to load the dictionary into memory, what other options I have.

Once thing I was thinking is to have the dictionary lucene indexed but I don't want a search based transaction.

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) page. Your question violates non-offtopic question rule.

Comment: Use a database.  Huge data lookups is pretty much what they’re for.

Answer (score 0):

**Here are some APIs you can consider implementing:**

https://sourceforge.net/projects/jazzy/

http://wiki.languagetool.org/java-spell-checker